# How to implement Minimum mean-squared error (MMSE) equalization?

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, filter-design, equalization, equalizer

I have the channel estimation and noise power estimation and I need a matlab implementation of time domain siso channel Equalization.

Theory:

Consider the FIR filter of length $N+1:$
$$
\hat{s}_{k}=\sum_{m=k-N}^{k} h_{k-m} y_{m}=\sum_{i=0}^{N} h_{i} y_{k-i}
$$
We need to find the coefficients $\left(h_{i}\right)$ that minimize the MSE:
$$
E\left(s_{k}-\hat{s}_{k}\right)^{2} \longrightarrow \min
$$
To find $\left(h_{i}\right),$ we can differentiate the error. More conveniently, start with the orthogonality principle:
$$
E\left[\left(s_{k}-\hat{s}_{k}\right) y_{k-j}\right]=0, \quad j=0,1, \ldots, N
$$
This gives
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\sum_{i=0}^{N} h_{i} E\left[y_{k-i} y_{k-j}\right]=E\left(s_{i} y_{k-j}\right) \\
\sum_{i=0}^{N} h_{i} R_{y}(i-j)=R_{x y}(j)
\end{array}
$$
In matrix form:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
R_{y}(0) & R_{y}(1) & \ldots & R_{y}(N) \\
R_{y}(1) & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
\ddots & \ddots & \ddots & R_{y}(1) \\
R_{y}(N) & \ddots & R_{y}(1) & R_{y}(0)
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
h_{0} \\
\vdots \\
\vdots \\
h_{X}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
R_{x y}(0) \\
\vdots \\
\vdots \\
R_{x y}(N)
\end{array}\right]
$$
$$
R_{v} h=r_{x y} \quad \Rightarrow h=R_{y}^{-1} r_{s y}
$$

How can I **introduce the noise power estimation** in my computations, and fine the **delay of the wiener solution** ?

Any help would be really appreciated

Here is my own matlab implementation

```
clear all;
clc; 
depth = 50; % solution depth 
ntaps = 8; 
MQAM = 2;
N = 1e2;
delay=floor(ntaps/2);
s = randi([0 1],1, N);
h = [1 0.5*exp(1i*pi/6)  0.1*exp(-1i*pi/8)]';
smod = qammod(s,MQAM,'gray','InputType','bit');
r = awgn(filter(h, 1,smod),0, 'measured');
A=convmtx(r(1:depth).',ntaps);
R=A'*A; 
X=[zeros(1,delay) s(1:depth) zeros(1,ceil(ntaps/2)-1)].';
ro=A'*X;
coeff=(inv(R)*ro);
decision = filter( r(1:depth),1, coeff);
dem = qamdemod(decision,MQAM,'gray','OutputType','bit'); 
cmp = [dem(1:10)', s(1:10)']
```

Here cmp is the concatenation of the input signal and dem is the output of the MMSE Equalization :we can see that because of the delay, dem and s don't match !

Comment: What is blocking you, you know the formula?

Comment: Cmp in my code don't match

Comment: Looks familiar! Can you provide more details on your input and what isn’t matching?

Comment: I've updated the post, cmp contains few values of the mmse Equalized signal and the input signal

Comment: I know it is the delay that I am not setting right  ... I need to fine tune the delay but how?